# Unit test for a method to check for possible memory leaks in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've a simple class EmployeeDAL class to fetch data from the database-

```
public class EmployeeDAL
    {
        public IDataReader FetchEmployees()
        {
            var con = new SqlConnection("constr");
            var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetEmployees", con);
            var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            return r;
        }
    }
```

Can we write unit test case for `FetchEmployees` method to check for possible memory leaks? Here I'm disposing `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects.

Comment: Did you mean to say you're *not* disposing of your connection and command objects?

Comment: Memory leaks are pretty rare in managed code. Not calling `Dispose` on an instance of a class that implements `IDisposable` isn't a *memory leak*; well, it may, but it would be a leak very far removed from your code (for example, not disposing Windows Forms controls would likely cause a Windows handle leak).  In any case, I have a hard time visualizing a *unit test* that could detect memory leaks or missing Dispose calls

Comment: Also, not related to your question, don't use "sp_" as your prefix for stored procedures: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/169/naming-conventions-for-sql-server-stored-procedures/#:~:text=Do%20not%20use%20sp_%20as,used%20in%20the%20master%20database.&text=So%20avoid%20using%20this%20as%20a%20naming%20convention.

Comment: @mason- Actually this an scenario where we sometime forgot to dispose objects in a method after using it. So I am looking an way to detect un-disposed objects in a method through unit tests.

Comment: @Flydog57- do you have any handy unit test to detect un-disposed objects in a method?